# Simple two-way encryption that outputs a long alphanumeric string

Tags: security, cakephp

Basically, I am writing e-mails that are sent when a person registers on my website, and it will have an activation link that needs to have a string assigned to a GET variable.

When the person clicks the link, they will be taken to a page on the site where the string will then be decrypted and matched to something in the database that is unique to them. It will then activate their account.

I'm doing this in CakePHP, so if there's any function built in, that would be preferable.

I've tried lots of options, and most of them either are really short, really strange, or have characters in them that would mess up the GET variable.

I need the output to be preferably around 20 characters, with only letters and numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a random, unique string. No need for encrypting or decrypting it, it just needs to be unique, long and random. That's simply known as an opaque token. It does not have any meaning, it's just something unique that only one user is supposed to have. [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid) are a great fit.

```
do {
    $token = str_replace('-', '', String::uuid());
} while (!$this->User->isUnique(array('token' => $token)));
```